# Android - update textview in same fragments by using viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have created five different `Fragment`s dynamically in `ViewPager` and each `Fragment` has a `TextView`. So if the `ViewPager` moves from one to another `Fragment`, I have planed to update the fragment position on the `TextView`. So I have created the `TextView` like:

```
public static  TextView txt_starProgress;
public static  TextView txt_radioProgress; 
public static  TextView txt_checkProgress;
public static  TextView txt_yesnoProgress;
public static  TextView txt_overallProgress;
```

on each `Fragment` and update the values from the `Activity` by the below code when the `ViewPager` move from one to another `Fragment`.

```
if(activities.contains("StarRatingActivity"))
StarRatingActivity.txt_starProgress.setText(Integer.toString(pageCount));
if(activities.contains("RadioButtonActivity"))
RadioButtonActivity.txt_radioProgress.setText(Integer.toString(pageCount));
if(activities.contains("CheckBoxActivity"))
CheckBoxActivity.txt_checkProgress.setText(Integer.toString(pageCount));
if(activities.contains("YesNoActivity"))
YesNoActivity.txt_yesnoProgress.setText(Integer.toString(pageCount));
if(activities.contains("OverallActivity"))
OverallActivity.txt_overallProgress.setText(Integer.toString(pageCount));
```

It works fine. Then I have created the same kind of five `Fragment`s dynamically and tryed to update the `TextView` but the page position does not get updated properly. How can i solved this one.

Comment: your question is unclear, please explain better,

Comment: Making any `View` `static` is a bad idea as it is a cause of [memory leaks](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/03/12/android-why-not-to-use-static-for-view-fields-in-your-activity-or-fragments-by-lars-vogel/)

Comment: How can i implement that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your ViewPager's TextView dynamically, Then all YOU have to call this method - `notifyonDataChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

you can create or passed through arguments of fragments in your pageradapter like this

```
YourFragment yourFragment = yourPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
Bundle arg = new Bundle();
arg.putString("string", string);
yourFragment.setArguments(extras);
return yourFragment;
```

in YourFragment.class you can get the passed value inside **onCreate()** like the code below

```
Bundle arg = getArguments();
String string = arg.getString("string");
```